# Which kind of data should be returned for DataTable in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I want to create dynamic load information for each page in `DataTable`.

I'm trying to follow these examples:

https://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side

https://www.datatables.net/manual/data

Code from example:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '/data-source',
        type: 'POST'
    }
} );
```

"/data-source" should return this kind of data:

```
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 57,
    "recordsFiltered": 57,
    "data": [
        [
            "Angelica",
            "Ramos",
            "System Architect",
            "London",
            "9th Oct 09",
            "$2,875"
        ],
        [
            "Ashton",
            "Cox",
            "Technical Author",
            "San Francisco",
            "12th Jan 09",
            "$4,800"
        ],
        ...
    ]
}
```

How can I create this kind of data in C# MVC, and convert it into js?

Comment: Json, in MVC C# use Action Return type `JsonResult` and return complex object as `return Json(yourobject)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 public ActionResult dataSource()
 {
    var data = new
    {
       recordsTotal = totalCount,
       recordsFiltered = filterCount,
       data = dataList
    };
    var jsonValue = Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);        
    return jsonValue;
}
```